# Maintaining Component Refs Through React.cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been testing the possible limitations/dangers of using `React.cloneElement()` to extend a component's `children`. One possible danger I've identified is the possible overwriting of props such as `ref` and `key`.

However, as per React's [0.13 release candidate](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html) (back in 2015):

> However, unlike JSX and cloneWithProps, it also preserves refs. This means that if you get a child with a ref on it, you won't accidentally steal it from your ancestor. You will get the same ref attached to your new element.
>
> [...]
>
> Note: `React.cloneElement(child, { ref: 'newRef' })` DOES override the ref so it is still not possible for two parents to have a ref to the same child, unless you use callback-refs.

I have written a [small React application](http://codepen.io/pvienneau/pen/PWJjKq?editors=0010) that clones children components pushed through, testing for the validity of refs at two levels:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);   
  
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.extendsChildren = this.extendChildren(this);
  }
  
  onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    try{
      alert(this._input.value);
    }catch(e){
      alert('ref broken :(');
    }
  }
  
  extendChildren(){
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(
        child,
        {
          ref: ref => this._input = ref
        }
      );
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>
        ChildComponent ref check
      </button>
      {this.extendChildren()}
    </div>
    );
  }
}


class AncestorComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    try{
      alert(this._input.value);
    }catch(e){
      alert('ref broken :(');
    }
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <p>
          The expected behaviour is that I should be able to click on both Application and ChildComponent check buttons and have a reference to the input (poping an alert with the input's value).
        </p>
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>
        Ancestor ref check
      </button>
      <ChildComponent>
        <input ref={ref => this._input = ref} defaultValue="Hello World"/>
      </ChildComponent>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, cloningElements inside my ChildComponent overwrites the AncestorComponent's `ref` prop from the input field, where I would expect that `ref` prop to be preserved, alongside the new `ref` I defined as part of the `React.cloneElement`.

You can test this by running the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pvienneau/pen/PWJjKq?editors=0010).

Is there anything I'm doing wrong, or has this feature been dropped since?

Answer (score 6):

As per Dan Abramov's [response](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8873#issuecomment-275423780), overwriting the reference, even with a callback, is still going to overwrite the reference. You'll need to call the current reference as part of the callback declaration:

```
return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
  React.cloneElement(child, {
    ref(node) {
      // Keep your own reference
      this._input = node;
      // Call the original ref, if any
      const {ref} = child;
      if (typeof ref === 'function') {
        ref(node);
      }
    }
  )
);
```